# docker: get files from one container to another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 docker containers which I created from 2 Dockerfiles.

```
docker run container1 # It updates a txt (update.txt) file every minutes and store it in the same container

docker run container2 --link container1 # A web server which in intended to read the updated file in container1
```

Now I want to access the file update.txt in container2 but I can't do that. I don't want to just copy the file since it will become static but I want to read the dynamically updated file to read the latest updates. Can anyone suggest a  way out?

Answer (score 3):

Use named volume to store update.txt in that volume on host.

Mount this volume in both containers.

All changes that container 1 writes then will be accessible in container 2.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a docker volume by using the below command

```
$ docker volume create --name sharedVolume
sharedVolume
```

And then start the first container by mounting the above-created volume and write data in that location where volume will be mounted.

```
$ docker run -it -v sharedVolume:/dataToWrite ubuntu
root@1021d9260d7b:/# echo "DATA Written" >> /dataToWrite/Example.txt
root@1021d9260d7b:/# cat /dataToWrite/Example.txt
DATA Written
```

Now, start the second container and mount the same volume you created above and check whether the same file present in the second container or not

```
$ docker run -it -v sharedVolume:/dataToWrite alpine
/ # cat /dataToWrite/Example.txt
DATA Written
```

As you can see above, the first container is ubuntu and the second container is alpine. Contents which are written in the first container is present in second container.